# I want to ask about this exceptionquestion

Tags: python, class, exception

Here is my code

```
class E3Exception(Exception):
  pass

class E3OddException(E3Exception):
  pass

def raiser (x):
  if (int(x)%2==1):
    raise E3OddException
  elif (int(x)%2==0):
    x=int(x)
  elif (x=='CSC148'):
    raise E3Exception('Hi Brian')
  elif (isinstance(x, str)==True & isinstance(int(x), int)==False &   x!='CSC148'): 
    raise ValueError
  else:
    raise TypeError
```

I tried to run raise(`CSC148`) but I kept getting the following error, does anyone know why?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException
```

Comment: Is `E3Exception` derived from [`Exception`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/exceptions.html#Exception)?

Comment: Show us how you have "tried to run raise CSC148"

Comment: Yea I tried    raise('CSC148') it always raise valueerror instead of the E3Exception

Comment: Yes the class derived from Exception

Comment: Are you doing `raise('CSC148')` or `raiser('CSC148')` (with an 'r' at the end)? The former is a `raise` statement (with unnecessary parentheses), rather than a call to your function.

Comment: sorry it is actually raiser('CSC148') and I am getting this error code

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 1, in <module>
    # Used internally for debug sandbox under external interpreter
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Wing IDE 101 5.1\src\debug\tserver\_sandbox.py", line 8, in raiser
builtins.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'CSC148'

Comment: It is the value error but I want it to jump into the E3Exception line

Comment: @AlexH: That's a different error than you're describing in the question. Can you edit to show the correct error, with the proper formatting?

Comment: Yea I just run it, the second error is the one i got